# About the canonical morphism $\mathcal{O}(1) \to f_* f^*\mathcal{O}(1)$ in projective space.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I was wondering if there is any reason to expect that given a closed subscheme $f:X \to \mathbb{P}^n_k$ we can say that $\mathcal{O}(1) \to f_* f^*\mathcal{O}(1)$ is injective.

I am working with $X$ a geometrically connected curve over $k$ which is a complete intersection.

Comment: No, there is no reason, since the sheaf on the RHS is supported on $X$.

Comment: As a simple example, you can take $f : X \to \Bbb P^2$ the inclusion of the line $x=0$. The map $\mathcal O(1) \to f_*f^* \mathcal O(1)$ is just taking a linear homogenous polynomial $l(x,y,z)$ and evaluate at $x=0$ which is definitely not injective.